# parse json that contains fields with same name in two (or more) objects with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

i have a json file that i want to parse it.
here is my json:

```
{
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 802,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description":"Rainy",
            "icon": "03d"
        }
    ],
    "visibility": 10000,
    "dt": 1497028800,
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "cod": 200
}
```

i want to parse this json to java code, so my code would look like this:

```
public class CurrentWeather {

    public class Weather{
        @SerializedName("id")
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("main")
        private String title;
        @SerializedName("description")
        private String description;
    }

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String city;
}
```

as you can see there is two "id" in the json; one in the json body and another in weather object and i'm using `@SerializedName("id")` for two fields in my java code. i'm sure this is not the right way.
so my question is what should i do to parse this piece of code?

Comment: You have id two times but not in the same class. Thats the right way. You just have to add a member of type Weather[] to your CurrentWeather class.

Comment: how come you try to parse a "description" in your weather object... there is no "description" key in your json example

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz sorry. somehow it got deleted. just fixed it

Comment: @rollback suppose there are more objects with "id" field in json, how gson knows which "id" is to be parsed? (sorry for bad English btw :) )

Comment: Gson starts with the root object. That root object has the keys "weather", "visibility", "dt", "id", "name" and "cod". The value behind key "weather" is a list of json objects, which have their own keys.

Comment: @rollback I got it. so Gson actually knows which id should be parsed! thank you! another thing: variables should be in same order as in json?

Comment: No. The order of variables in the Java code doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CurrentWeather {

    private List<Weather> weather;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String city;
}

 public class Weather{
        @SerializedName("id")
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("main")
        private String title;
        @SerializedName("description")
        private String description;
    }
```